# Elgg error configure web server with Elgg's rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, elgg

Where do I need to edit and put the rewrite mod in elgg?

The Server is hosted on II7 at Goddady. I need help with elgg error

> "You need to configure your web server with Elgg's rewrite rules and try again"

Here is what I have done so far by editing the htaccess_dist file.

```
My Example:

# Elgg htaccess directives

<Files "htaccess_dist">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

# Don't allow listing directories
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php


############################
# BROWSER CACHING

# The expires module controls the Expires and Cache-Control headers. Elgg sets
# these for dynamically generated files so this is just for static files.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Conditional requests are controlled through Last-Modified and ETag headers.
# Elgg sets these on dynamically generated cacheable files so this is just for
# static files. Note: Apache sends Last-Modified by default on static files so
# I don't think we need to be sending ETag for these files.
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp3|flv|mov|avi|3pg|html|htm|swf|js|css|ico)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>


############################
# PHP SETTINGS
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    # limit the maximum memory consumed by the php script to 64 MB
    php_value memory_limit 64M
    # register_globals is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 - disable it for security reasons.
    php_value register_globals 0
    # post_max_size is the maximum size of ALL the data that is POST'ed to php at a time (8 MB)
    php_value post_max_size 8388608
    # upload_max_filesize is the maximum size of a single uploaded file (5 MB)
    php_value upload_max_filesize 5242880
    # on development servers, set to 1 to display errors. Set to 0 on production servers.
    php_value display_errors 0
</IfModule>


############################
# COMPRESSION

# Turn on mod_gzip if available
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk yes
    mod_gzip_keep_workfiles No
    mod_gzip_minimum_file_size 1000
    mod_gzip_maximum_file_size 1000000
    mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size 1000000
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
    # Exclude old browsers and images since IE has trouble with this
    mod_gzip_item_exclude reqheader "User-Agent: .*Mozilla/4\..*\["
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
</IfModule>

## Apache2 deflate support if available
##
## Important note: mod_headers is required for correct functioning across proxies.
##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.[0678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

    # The following is to disable compression for actions. The reason being is that these
    # may offer direct downloads which (since the initial request comes in as text/html and headers
    # get changed in the script) get double compressed and become unusable when downloaded by IE.
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI action\/* no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI actions\/* no-gzip dont-vary

</IfModule>


############################
# REWRITE RULES

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# If Elgg is in a subdirectory on your site, you might need to add a RewriteBase line
# containing the path from your site root to elgg's root. e.g. If your site is
# http://example.com/ and Elgg is in http://example.com/sites/elgg/, you might need


#
# My example
RewriteBase http://www.the_website_url.com/elgg/

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="=&quot;^action/([A-Za-z0-9_/-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/action_handler.php?action={R:1}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^services/api/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/service_handler.php?handler={R:1}&amp;request={R:2}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" 

appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^export/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="services/export/handler.php?view={R:1}&amp;guid={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4">
                    <match url="^export/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="services/export/handler.php?view={R:1}&amp;guid={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
                    <match url="^export/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="services/export/handler.php?view={R:1}&amp;guid={R:2}&amp;type={R:3}&amp;idname={R:4}" 

appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 6">
                    <match url="^_css/css.css$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="_css/css.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 7">
                    <match url="^pg/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/pagehandler.php?handler={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" 

appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 8">
                    <match url="^pg/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/pagehandler.php?handler={R:1}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" 

/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 9">
                    <match url="xml-rpc.php" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 10">
                    <match url="mt/mt-xmlrpc.cgi" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 11">
                    <match url="^tag/(.+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="engine/handlers/pagehandler.php?handler=search&amp;page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

#
# here, only without the # in front.
#
# If you're not running Elgg in a subdirectory on your site, but still getting lots
# of 404 errors beyond the front page, you could instead try:
#
#RewriteBase /


# If your users receive the message "Sorry, logging in from a different domain is not permitted"
# you must make sure your login form is served from the same hostname as your site pages.
# See http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Login_token_mismatch_error for more info.
#
# If you must add RewriteRules to change hostname, add them directly below (above all the others)


# In for backwards compatibility
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&page=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^tag\/(.+)\/?$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=search&page=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^action\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\/]+)$ engine/handlers/action_handler.php?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^cache\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/cache_handler.php?request=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^services\/api\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/service_handler.php?handler=$1&request=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?view=$1&guid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)\/$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?

view=$1&guid=$2&type=$3&idname=$4 [L]

RewriteRule xml-rpc.php engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php [L]
RewriteRule mt/mt-xmlrpc.cgi engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php [L]


# rule for rewrite module test during install - can be removed after installation
RewriteRule ^rewrite.php$ install.php [L]

# Everything else that isn't a file gets routed through the page handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?    handler=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also running elgg on IIS 7.5, and had a lot of trouble setting it up, untill I found this post: http://community.elgg.org/discussion/view/486696/elgg-on-iis-7
This should get you going:

1) Install the IIS URL Rewrite module: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

2) Open the IIS Manager in Control Panel > Administrative Tools

3) Right-Click on your Elgg site and select "Switch to Features View" if not already there.

4) Open the URL Rewrite Feature and click "Import Rules..." in the actions menu.

5) Browse for a configuration file... Open the "htaccess_dist" file located in the root directory of your elgg site.

6) Under each rule there is a match tag. The tags contain regular expressions. Most regular expressions will generate an error because IIS is interpreting them differently than Apache would. There is a simple fix. In every instance you see "_" remove the slash. It is an escape character for the underscore. This isn't necessary for IIS and will generate an error. Be sure to remove it anytime you see it before the underscore, there should be 7 instance as far as I can remember.

8) In the actions menu on the right, hit apply.

It wil be saved as a webconfig file n the root of elgg installation.
That's it! Elgg should now work on IIS.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is great!

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess file is specific to Apache server. If you want to use IIS server, you need to port rewrite rules to their format.

Have a look at some old rules for Elgg 1.7: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Elgg_and_IIS You'd need to port rules for Elgg 1.8.